# выборка финальных значений в промежутке и нахождение несуществующих значений

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, postgresql, запрос

всем привет!
прошу помощи начинающему, есть 3 таблицы: две из них - с данными о товарах (на уровне магазина и области), третья - связывает первые две посредством кодов (магазина и области)

[image: Таблицы БД (zone; loc; zone_loc)]

таблица, которая связывает выше перечисленные по кодам обл/магазина (один магазин может находится только в одной области, но в одной области может находится несколько магазинов) (zone_loc)

Имеются 2 вопроса.
Первый: нужно написать запрос, показывающий цену для товаров, находящейся в первой (zone = 1) области на начало и конец периода (1.06.2015 по 20.07.2016)
вот что есть на данный момент

```
SELECT item, ac_date, price
FROM zone
WHERE ac_date <= '2015.6.1' AND zone_id = 1
UNION 
SELECT item, ac_date, price
FROM loc a
JOIN zone_loc b
ON a.loc_id = b.loc_id
WHERE a.ac_date <= '2015.6.1' AND b.zone_id = 1
UNION 
SELECT item, ac_date, price
FROM zone  
WHERE ac_date = '2016.7.20' AND zone_id = 1 
UNION 
SELECT item, ac_date, price
FROM loc a
JOIN zone_loc b
ON a.loc = b.loc
WHERE a.ac_date = '2016.7.20' AND b.zone_id = 1;
```

проблема заключается в том, что не все товары изменили цены прямо в последний день периода (2016.7.20), поэтому при изменении варианта с

```
WHERE ac_date = '2016.7.20'
```

на

```
WHERE ac_date BETWEEN '2015.6.2' AND'2016.7.20'
```

в выборку попадают промежуточные значения, которые к концу периода изменили свою цену. 
Как нужно изменить запрос, чтобы в выборке на конец периода отображались только товары с конечными ценами? 
И как можно изменить запрос, не используя union?

Есть еще один вопрос, нужно создать такой запрос, который бы показывал цену товара на уровне магазина (табл. loc), которой нет на уровне области, к которой привязан магазин. Здесь, как я понял, должно быть соответствие по датам (помимо всего прочего - id товара, zone to loc). По этому заданию у меня вообще никаких годных наработок нет, есть мысль, что это все должно с таблицей товаров магазина (loc) через таблицу связи (zone_loc) с таблицей товаров области (zone), а дальше через оператор EXISTS находить те записи, которых нет в таблице zone

```
SELECT a.item, a.loc_id, c.zone_id, a.ac_date, a.price
FROM loc a JOIN zone_loc b 
ON a.loc_id = b.loc_id
JOIN zone c
ON b.zone_id = c.zone_id
WHERE a.item = c.item 
AND a.ac_date = c.ac_date;
```

Но это совсем не то, и как дальше использовать EXISTS (если вообще правильно его тут использовать) и прийти к верному решению не знаю.
Буду благодарен любой помощи в этих вопросах!

Comment: Почему у вас в тегах указаны несколько СУБД. Синтаксис sql-server и postrgesql отличается. особенно, когда идет речь о нестандартных запросах. Укажите точно свою СУБД. Кроме того, для решения необходимо в текстовом виде дать образец входных данных и показать какой результат ожидается получить, из вашего текстового описания сложно понять что именно требуется

Comment: На вскидку, по первому вопросу, возможно подойдут функции first_value и last_value с order by в over() по дате и partition по товару

Answer (score 1):

Очень непонятно поставлен вопрос. Но попробую написать хоть что-то.

Для начала вам не нужна третья таблица. Связь "один-ко-многому" делается без промежуточной таблицы. Она нужна для "многое-ко-многому". Просто добавьте в таблице магазина ещё одно поле - идешку локации в которой магазин расположен.

Про первый ваш вопрос. Если вам нужна цена на начало периода - просто сделайте запрос на эту цену: ограничьте область поиска нужными датами, отсортируйте выборку и возьмите первую запись. Для последней даты периода сделайте тоже самое, но отсортируйте выборку в обратную сторону.

В примере ниже нет группировки по товарам, вам её остаётся добавить (на макете я завёл только один товар для тестов).

```
(
    SELECT 'цена на начало периода' price_type, item, ac_date, price
    FROM zone
    WHERE ac_date BETWEEN '2015-06-01' AND '2016-07-20'
    ORDER BY ac_date ASC
    LIMIT 1
) UNION (
    SELECT 'цена к концу периода' price_type, item, ac_date, price
    FROM zone
    WHERE ac_date BETWEEN '2015-06-01' AND '2016-07-20'
    ORDER BY ac_date DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
```

Получится что-то вроде этого:

```
price_type               item   ac_date     price  
-----------------------  -----  ----------  ------
цена на начало периода       1  2015-06-01     100
цена к концу периода         1  2016-07-20     200
```

Тестировал на данных:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE zone(item INT, zone_id INT, ac_date DATE, price INT)
-- цена до периода
SELECT 1 item, 1 zone_id, '2015-05-01' ac_date, 500 price UNION
-- начало периода
SELECT 1 item, 1 zone_id, '2015-06-01' ac_date, 100 price UNION
-- промежуточные колебания цены
SELECT 1 item, 1 zone_id, '2015-06-02' ac_date, 150 price UNION
SELECT 1 item, 1 zone_id, '2015-06-03' ac_date, 250 price UNION
SELECT 1 item, 1 zone_id, '2015-06-04' ac_date,  50 price UNION
SELECT 1 item, 1 zone_id, '2015-06-05' ac_date, 120 price UNION
-- конец периода
SELECT 1 item, 1 zone_id, '2016-07-20' ac_date, 200 price UNION
-- цена после периода
SELECT 1 item, 1 zone_id, '2016-07-25' ac_date, 500 price
```

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую реализовать предложенное Вами. Только как я понял, нужно таким образом упорядочить изменения цен товаров и взять последние текущие цены до начала периода (включая первый день 2015-06-01, ибо последнее изменение цены может быть до начала периода), а затем упорядочить их с DESC как во втором SELECT в вашем примере. И затем взять уже промежуток расчетного периода от 2015-06-02 до 2016-07-20 включительно таким же образом с DESC. Сразу встает вопрос, по какому(каким) столбцу делать группировку, если один товар (с одним и тем же id) имеет несколько записей с разными датами и ценами

Comment: Если нужна цена на момент входа в отчётный период, то `where ac_date < 'начало_периода' order by ac_date desc limit 1`. На момент выхода из периода просто поменять дату на дату окончания периода. Группировка зависит от цены, которая вам нужна. Из вопроса вообще не ясно какую проблему вы пытаетесь решить и какие к ней бизнес-требования.